# Problem to transfer public variable to other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, variables, public, transfer

I'm cleaning my macros (20 VBA modules in excel) that create an overall project report based on 10 different excel files with several tabs.

I'd like to simplify my data exchange code

from :

```
Set InitRNG = Workbooks("Master - PSSR.xlsm").Worksheets("PSSRList").Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
Set TargetRNG = Workbooks("Master - turnover Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Lib_PSSR").Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
Call TransfRange(InitRNG, TargetRNG)
```

To:

```
Set InitRNG = WBMpssr.Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
Set TargetRNG = WBMpssrlistRange("A2:C" & LastRow)
Call TransfRange(InitRNG, TargetRNG)
```

So i got to declare simplified workbook and worksheet name as public
Easy to do, but not working

Here are the simple test i've done

In thisworkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Public WBmaster As Workbook
Public WSMgraph As Worksheet
Public WSMminitables As Worksheet
Public WSMtable As Worksheet
Public x As String

Sub Workbook_Open()

Set WBmaster = Workbooks("Master - Turnover report.xlsm")

Set WSMgraph = WBmaster.Worksheets("4graph")
Set WSMminitables = WBmaster.Worksheets("MiniTables")
Set WSMtable = WBmaster.Worksheets("Table")


x = "blabla"
MsgBox "x=" & x

End Sub
```

Works fine, "x=blabla" appears

then the main macro, in a module

```
Sub Main()
MsgBox "x=" & x
End Sub
```

answer is "x="
Lost the value....
What am I doing wrong

Comment: Try declaring `x` in a normal module rather than the worbook module.

Comment: Variables only are used within the run, giving a variable value on the `Workbook_Open` event, if the  `Main()` procedure doesn't run on the same event it will empty all your variables. You need to give value to your variables on the same "run" of your code, for each run your variables will be reset. If you need to hold something between runs, get a hidden sheet and hold there anything you need.

Comment: [Understanding the lifetime of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables).  As @SJR said - declare `x` at the top of a normal module.